# Python if no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones

Estoy creando un codigo en python y en el siguiente fragmento de codigo me ocurre un fallo que no entiendo:

```
for x in cadena:
    letradeinicio1 = False
    if n==0 or x == " ":
      if letradeinicio1 == False:
        letradeinicio1 = True
        letradeinicio2 = n
        print(letradeinicio1)
      else:
        palabras.append(cadena[letradeinicio2:n])
```

Siempre que se ejecuta el codigo que contiene el primer if tambien se ejecuta el que contiene el segundo, aunque lo que deberia ocurrir seria que el segundo if solo se deberia ejecutar una vez, ya que la variable letradeinicio1 pasa a ser True la primera vez que se ejecuta el if y no deberia ejecutarse mas. El codigo se comporta de la misma forma que si huviese sido:

```
for x in cadena:
    letradeinicio1 = False
    if n==0 or x == " ":
       letradeinicio1 = True
       letradeinicio2 = n
       print(letradeinicio1)
```

Agradeceria mucho si alguien me explicase donde falla el codigo.

Comment: No tiene sentido lo que estás haciendo. Para cada iteración del ```for``` estás asignando a ```False``` la variable ```letradeinicio1``` por lo que más adelante cuando haces la comprobación ```letradeinicio1 == False``` siempre va a ser ```true``` y entrará en la condición.

Comment: Es cierto que cambia a `True` en cuanto entra en el segundo `if`, pero cuando vuelve a ejecutar la siguiente iteracion del `for`, se vuelve a poner a `False`. Tal vez lo que necesites es poner `letradeinicio1 = False` fuera del loop para que no se vuelva a poner en `False`.

Answer (score 2):

el fallo puede estar acá:

```
for x in cadena:
letradeinicio1 = False
if n==0 or x == " ":
  if letradeinicio1 == False:
    letradeinicio1 = True
    letradeinicio2 = n
    print(letradeinicio1)
  else:
    palabras.append(cadena[letradeinicio2:n])
```

dices que cada vez que entre a este iterador letradeinicio1=False, entonces obviamente va a entrar en el 2 if porque en ese momento letradeinicio1 es False.

Después va valer True, pero recuerda que el ciclo va volver a empezar y nuevamente letrainicio1 va ser False.

intenta algo así:

```
letradeinicio1 = False
for x in cadena:
  if n==0 or x == " ":
    if letradeinicio1 == False:
      letradeinicio1 = True
      letradeinicio2 = n
      print(letradeinicio1)
    else:
      palabras.append(cadena[letradeinicio2:n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso te ocurre por que esta inicializando `letradeinicio` a `False` en cada iteracion del for, para que se comporte tal como tu quieres debes inicializar la variable antes de comenzar el bucle, de esta manera:

```
letradeinicio1 = False
for x in cadena:
    if n==0 or x == " ":
        if letradeinicio1 == False:
            letradeinicio1 = True
            letradeinicio2 = n
            print(letradeinicio1)
        else:
            palabras.append(cadena[letradeinicio2:n])
```